# Excel VBA InputBox Range Selection Button

Tags: vba, excel

Ok. So I'm familiar with InputBoxs in VBA to some degree. I'm aware of the `Type:=8` requirement to select a range. My code works fine and allows me to do what I want to.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

However, I want to generate the same type of inputbox that Exel itself generates when selecting a range.

[image]

I've been searching through various online resources and the only thing that comes up again and again is that `Type:=8` needs to be used. The MS Help has also not been of much help.

For completness' sake here is my code:

```
Dim SelRng1 As Range
Dim SelRng2 As Range

Set SelRng1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the first table (headers included)", Title:="Select Table 1", Type:=8)
Set SelRng2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the second table (headers included)", Title:="Select Table 1", Type:=8)
```

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own form and [put the `RefEdit` control on it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213776).

Comment: Of course, the RefEdit is flaky as anything. I've written an article about using InputBox as an [Alternative to Excel's Flaky RefEdit Control](http://peltiertech.com/refedit-control-alternative/). It's not as "nice", but it doesn't crash on 5% of users' machines.